# what is $0 and %0 in lighttpd configuration?

Tags: lighttpd

so in this doc,
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToRedirectHttpToHttps

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    # capture vhost name with regex conditiona -> %0 in redirect pattern
    # must be the most inner block to the redirect rule
    $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
        url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
    }
}
```

http://1.2.3.4/dir/
what is %0 and what is $0 please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are RegEx symbols. According to your lighttpd configuration this is how the symbols are resolved.

`%0` - your host name (or virtual hostname, like ftp.website.com)

`$0` - Directory, if any (like /files , etc)

Here `%0` will be replaced by the string matching the regexp `".*"` in `$HTTP["host"]` and `$0` just gets placed the end of the host name string according to regex `".*"` and puts the name of the directory at the end. (eg, /files , /index , etc)

EDIT : **Note that $ refers to the directory path and % refers to the hostname. Normally if there is no regex condition other than `".*"`, we would just append 0 at the end to display the hostname or directory path as it is. But if we are using RegEx to modify the hostname/directory path to be re-written, we append 1,2, etc depending on the positon of the RegEx (subexpressions). Look at the examples below for your understanding.**

**Regarding `$1,$2` - these are used when there are multiple regexes for the directory bit. Example and explanation**

```
url.redirect = ( "^/show/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$" => "http://www.example.org/show.php?isdn=$1&page$2",
             "^/get/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$"  => "http://www.example.org/get.php?isdn=$1&page$2" )
```

Observe the regex in the top example
`^/show/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$`. Note that the `/` refers to the directory backslash. The RegExes are `([0-9]+)` which just accepts all numbers exclusively, , the `^` sign which signifies the start of the string, and the dollar sign `$`, which signifies the end of the string/link. The `^` and `$` sign are mandatory, so those wont be included in the regex numbering.

Assume a directory `/show/3/4` is requested from the lighttpd server.

$0 refers to the directory path `/show/3/4` as it is

$1 refers to the output received from the first regex condition `([0-9]+)` placed just between `/show` and `/([0-9]+)$`, in this case it is 3

$2 refers to the output received from the second (and the last) regex condition `([0-9]+)` placed at the end just before the `$` , in this case it is 4.

So in the end the `$1` and `$2` get resolved. This would resolve and redirect a directory path URI like `/show/3/4` to `http://www.example.org/get.php?isdn=3&page4`

However, instead if you replaced $1 and $2 with $0, you would get something like this 
`http://www.example.org/show.php?isdn=/show/3/4/&page/show/3/4/`

Not exactly something that you want when you are creating rewrites for APIs.

**Regarding `%1,%2` , these are used when there are multiple regexes for the hostname. Example and explanation**

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.(.*)$" {
  url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://%1/$1" )
}
```

Here our Regex for the hostname as given above is `^www\.(.*)$` which matches everything preceeding the URI string `www.`. By mentioning `%1` for the URL, the RegEx is applied to the hostname.

You can see that there is a separate RegEx for the directory path as well. The Regex for the directory path is `^/(.*)`, which matches everything but a line break. By mentioning `$1`, the RegEx is applied to the directory path.
Here we can see that both `%` and `$` are used in combination.

This particular regex just converts a www link to an http one.
Example inputs and outputs
`http://www.example.com/test1` would get converted to `http://example.com/test1`

Hope this clears up the confusion.

[More info :](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modredirect)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that link doesn't explain what's is "$1", not impressed by lighttpd's doc and their horrible support.

Comment: Also i'm still confused by $0 and $1, this link uses $1 https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modredirect, vs the sample in my original post uses $0, confused ...

Comment: Check the edit above. I've tried my best to explain how it is. This from my experience through trial and error from running a lighttpd server. Hope it helps :)

Comment: really appreciate this, you have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

$1-$9 are the regex matches of the url.redirect or url.rewrite statement

%1-%9 are the regex matches of the $HTTP[...] =~ or !~ condition which contains the url.redirect or url.rewrite statement, if url.redirect or url.rewrite statements are within a regex condition

$0 or %0 is the entire string matched by the corresponding regex, even if regex captures (parentheses) are not used.